# Show image from cursor saved as memo field in report in FoxPro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am trying to show an image from a cursor i have which is in a memo filed using STRTOFILE() but when it saves the image to the location i specified the image is corrupted. Is there another way to get my image from a memo field from cursor?

Comment: Why would it get corrupted? You are surely doing something wrong. Would you share your code.

Comment: Don't store images in the database. Store a file on the filesystem and the a path to the file in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save image encoded as base64 using STRCONV( cExpression,13) , decode and use it with STRCONV( cExpresssion,14).

Comment: I don't think you need to do this. A memo can simply keep any characters and thus binary data as is (or you could use a Blob field - type w - if you wish).

Comment: I've used the blob field, but found it was taking up too much space, always end up using a field with the path to the image, made it easier to replace images and display them....I guess it's all what we're used to

Comment: @Hank, that is not quite true. Blob doesn't take more space, it only shows as if it is taking more space, since it is visually hex encoded version of binary data. You can simply store in a memo field. Storing just path is based on the limitations of VFP tables being limited tp 2 Gb, not because we wanted to. A better approach is to use something like postgreSQL, MS SQL Server ... as the backend where you directly store images in db.

Comment: You are right Cetin.. Blob should do. Though saving as Base64 has some benefits.. it suits better for serving html back ends , serialize / deserialize as xml/json,  and ensures simple compatibility with any RDBMS using long text columns.

Comment: @mplaza, saving as base64 would cause it to waste space. One could convert to base64 on demand, or save as is where needed. I am not against saving as base64, can be, although unnecessary. What I don't understand "why would it get corrupted". I believe OP has some code causing it but she\he didn't share the code.